# I want to create a helicopter carrying a logo or any element and make it move,

Tags: physics

I want to create a helicopter carrying a logo or any element and make it move, and the element is affected by the movement

I want the element or logo to be attached to the helicopter by ropes, and the ropes to have a physical effect with the movement, so that with the movement of the helicopter, the ropes and the element are affected.

Comment: Hello and welcome. What is your question really? Could you edit your post and show us what you have already and where you are stuck?

Comment: i still have no idea, what you wanna make? a flag hanging on the helicopter?

Comment: I think people voted to close this question because there is not really a question. For example a question like *Which physics simulation to use to....?* or *How to simulate a helicopter with ...?*)

Comment: To me it sounds like it's about how to realise the scene ( helicopter+rope+load/logo) and what physics simulation can be used to simulate the movement of the logo when the helicopter is moving.  I would try a *Cloth* simulation with a Vertex Parent relationship. Have a look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/239911/107598 and here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/248324/107598. These examples also use a Rigid Body simulation but I don't think you need it. Animate only the helicopter and the load should follow then.

Comment: But perhaps Simulation/Geometry Nodes would be better, since the movement is very slow and sluggish. Which Blender version do you use?

Comment: He wants an helicopter that carries an object with the help of cables, the difficulty here is that there are several cables, not just one

Comment: A sketch would help, I guess. In my imagination it looks like this: https://news.sky.com/story/sound-of-moosic-swiss-cows-airlifted-off-mountain-pastures-ahead-of-annual-parade-12392637. Why would multiple cables be more difficult than one,  @moonboots? One cable for the simulation and multiple fake cables for the show, no? (except you want to have a cable that breaks)

Comment: Oh yes you may be right, if it looks like that it will be easier than long cables

Comment: So I guess a drawing of what he wants would help

Answer (score 2):

If there is one main rope then small ropes at the bottom you can do it this way: Create your 3 objects, the small ropes at the bottom are part of the logo (here sphere) object. Give a *Cloth* simulation to the rope with the top vertices as *Pin Group*, parent it to the helicopter. Select the logo, shift select the rope, select 3 vertices at the bottom of the rope and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Parent to Vertex*:

[image]

Result when you animate the helicopter:

[image]

Comment: The helicopter model is awesome! :D for even more realism you should animate the rotor! https://i.stack.imgur.com/wi5yP.gif

Comment: wow nice, i don't see the cow though